# Omission of "to" with deontic "have to"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, modal-verbs

In the following sentence from The New Yorker (emphasis added)

> Sarkozy [...] has spent much of his campaign trying to woo voters away from Le Pen [...] and he is only going to **have grovel** for them more

there seems to be the omission of "to" with deontic "have to," with the intent to avoid the sequence of "to ... to." Is that so or is it just a misprint?

Comment: Looks like an error/misprint to me.

Comment: Funny, even though you bolded "have grovel", I automatically read "have to grovel", and only on second reading I spotted the mistake... Agree with Mitch, it's a misprint.

Comment: For shame, *The New Yorker*. For shame. You used to be beautiful, man.

Comment: Too localised - it's a misprint (more correctly, as @Kris says, it's *mis-subbed text*).

Comment: What do you mean by "mis-subbed text"? Can you explain it to me? Thank you.

Comment: @Giorgiomastrò I think they mean that the [sub-editor](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/subeditor) overlooked this mistake. In bygone times on Fleet Street, it might have been because he was passed out under his desk with an empty whiskey bottle next to him, but those glory days of journalism are long past :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no analogous examples in the Corpus of Contemporary American English. I think you can write it off as an error.

Answer (score 0):

Mis-subbed text.

(The author's idea could not be that the reader, by conditioning, will read it with a *to* inserted, as one answerer here pointed out having done).